# RSA keys not authenticating

Tags: server, ssh, authentication, openssh

Just trying to get a basic setup of openSSH going on an Ubuntu box to work remotely. Main issue: RSA keys fail auth. ssh DOES work using the password for auth, but I would much rather limit it to only allow ssh keys for auth.

Note that I refer to desktop and laptop. Desktop: machine acting as server. Laptop: machine acting as client.

Things that I have tried:

- verifying permissions
- regenerating keys
- transferring public keys using ssh-copy-id and directly via copy and paste
- different client machines
- running restorecon -Rv ~/.ssh (even though most posts say this applies mainly to CentOS, may as well try everything)
- and a whole lot of googling that has led to here

The relevant things I can think to include are the -vvv when attempting to connect on the laptop, the permissions of ~/.ssh on both machines, sshd_config on desktop, relevant entries in var/log/auth.log on the desktop. Obviously, if there is anything else that I can include that could help anyone resolve this issue, I will gladly provide relevant info.

Here is the -vvv when trying to auth:

```
➜  /home/troy 
≫  ssh -vvv -i .ssh/id_rsa lenny@xxx.xxx.xxx.229 -p xxx40
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "xxx.xxx.xxx.229" port xxx40
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.229 [xxx.xxx.xxx.229] port xxx40.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/troy/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/troy/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to xxx.xxx.xxx.229:xxx40 as 'lenny'
debug3: put_host_port: [xxx.xxx.xxx.229]:xxx40
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/troy/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/troy/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [xxx.xxx.xxx.229]:xxx40
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:M57GEOh/5elIh2RU446bRCamJ21QosRFOYaYx8u5Za4
debug3: put_host_port: [xxx.xxx.xxx.229]:xxx40
debug3: put_host_port: [xxx.xxx.xxx.229]:xxx40
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/troy/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/troy/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [xxx.xxx.xxx.229]:xxx40
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/troy/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/troy/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from [xxx.xxx.xxx.229]:xxx40
debug1: Host '[xxx.xxx.xxx.229]:xxx40' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/troy/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: .ssh/id_rsa (0x55a0c58221f0), explicit, agent
debug2: key: /home/troy/.ssh/id_rsa (0x55a0c582fe00), agent
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: .ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/troy/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

And here is ~/.ssh on the desktop:

```
lenny@Timubukuntu:~/.ssh$ ls -la
total 12
drwx------.  2 lenny lenny 4096 Feb 27 21:49 .
drwxr-x---. 21 lenny lenny 4096 Feb 27 22:16 ..
-rw-------.  1 lenny lenny 1146 Feb 27 20:35 authorized_keys
```

And the ~/.ssh on the laptop:

```
➜  /home/troy/.ssh 
≫  ls -la
total 20
drwx------  2 troy users 4096 Feb 27 21:53 .
drwx------ 30 troy users 4096 Feb 27 23:03 ..
-rw-------  1 troy users 1679 Feb 27 20:32 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 troy users  394 Feb 27 20:32 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 troy users 1416 Feb 27 15:13 known_hosts
```

And the sshd_config on the desktop:

```
lenny@Timubukuntu:/etc/ssh$ cat sshd_config
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for
Port xxx40 
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile  home/lenny/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

And here is the relevant info in /var/log/auth.log on the desktop:

```
Feb 27 22:52:31 Timubukuntu sshd[1901]: Connection closed by 67.20.206.135 port 36566 [preauth]
```

Comment: relevant ssh log should be found in `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/secure`  - please add it to your question, it help identify the problem.

Comment: Tun on `LogLevel DEBU3` in `sshd_config`, restart the service, try to connect and then paste related parts of the log.

Answer (score 0):

The home directory can't be writable by anyone but the user for key permissions to work. The file will be ignored otherwise

Try `chown -R troy:troy /home/troy/`

Also I think you are missing a `/` in this part of sshd_config

`AuthorizedKeysFile  home/lenny/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Permissions on both troy and home good, same on the remote server, ran that command just for good measure

drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Feb  1 20:45 home

drwx------ 30 troy users  4096 Feb 27 23:33 troy

Comment: Can you try `chown` 'ing  it to `troy:troy` instead of `troy:users` .

Can you also try changing this part of `sshd_config`,  `AuthorizedKeysFile  home/lenny/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Comment: Tried both versions in sshd_config `home/lenny` and `~/` - no change

Comment: Triple checked the permissions again. It all seems to line up with what everyone says they should be. And I tried multiple clients, with the correct permissions. And for what it's worth, this ssh key _does_ work with git (not sure if that is indicative of anything in this situation). 

Thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Oh, okay I see what you are saying now about users. Sorry for misunderstanding.

`drwx------ 30 troy troy 4.0K Feb 28 00:09 troy` it did not seem to help unfortunately.

Comment: The default for the entry in `sshd_conf` is `AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys`, where `%h` means home directory. Try to set it that way, or comment the line.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issues was with the incorrect shell exec.

```
journalctl -f
....
Feb 25 11:45:54 59a02b89e0f6 sshd[]: User user not allowed because shell /usr/bin/env /bin/bash does not exist
....
```

Changed /etc/passwd file for that user

```
vi /etc/passwd 
....
user:x:1000:1000::/home/user:/bin/bash
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on CentOS 7. I am a regular Debian-based Linux user so I was a fish out of the water. I noticed that in some of the servers it worked and in just one it didn't. The audit.log said nothing useful and the secure.log did not give anything either.
I found that the only real difference was some security context differences on files and directories between those that worked and those that didn't. Get the security with

`sudo ls -laZ <user-home>/.ssh`

of the directory (I'm assuming a lot of defaults on sshd_config).

You should see some `ssh_home_t` and `user_home_t` attributes. If you don't, use the `chcon` command to add the missing attributes.

For example

```
home="$(getent passwd <user> | cut -d: -f6)"
sudo chcon -R unconfined_u:object_r:ssh_home_t:s0 "$home".ssh
sudo chcon unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 "$home"
```

In my case, my suspicion is that the user was created in a non standard way. His home was a directory in `/var/lib`.

More info in: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/selinux-preventing-ssh-login-with-~-ssh-authorized_keys-4175469538/